# Postgre SQL LIKE for Integer

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I've some problem in my project, we use PostgreSQL and Hibernate as ORM.
I want to perform search in my table for any column type (INTEGER, STRING, TEXT).
Where are some problem with Hibernate, I know what I can execute for example LIKE operator
on INTEGER type like this:

```
select * from Table1 where size::text like '%3';
```

But damn Hibernate takes ::TEXT as self parameter and throws exception.
How I can avoid this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try doing:

```
cast(size as text)
```

It should help.

Comment: Thanks, It helps me! Btw I've found this solution:Predicate parcelNumberIdPredicate = cb.like(
                    parcelDO.<Long> get("parcelNumberId").as(String.class),
                    parcelNumberId + "%");

Answer (score 4):

Use CAST:

```
select * from Table1 where CAST(size AS text) like '%3';
```

Answer (score 3):

This may not answer your question, however if you want to find numbers that ends with `3` use the module operator

```
select * from Table1 where (size % 10) == 3;
```

Comment: If one needs "like" for integer, something looks awfully wrong.

Comment: I agree, but for my very simple task it's can be applied.

Comment: BTW, Konrad can you please propound more effective method?

Comment: I agree that this task is evidence of a code smell, but I needed to construct a query to mirror the partial-match logic that a user can enjoy in a DataTable column.  (It was working fine before we migrated to Postgres; now the Postgres query with `my_int_column::VARCHAR LIKE '%88%'` just spins and cripples my server.)