# Search bar inop when deployed to heroku (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, heroku, deployment

I am trying to work out my first search bar, but I am beginning to become confused between testing on my heroku deploy vs my localhost.

I have it working as it should on localhost, but when it is deployed for production it no longer works, this is my error from Heroku Logs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer ~~* unknown
```

Search bar form:

```
<%= form_tag(tools_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Tools" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

My Display is supposed to redirect to an index of said search term

and my controller looks like so:

```
  def index
    @tools = Tool.paginate(params[:page], :per_page => 50)
    if params[:search]
      @tools = Tool.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
    else
      @tools = Tool.paginate(params[:page], :per_page => 50)
    end

end
```

I have done some research, but all I've really come up with is that PG may not be able to search integers, which would explain why in development with sqlite it works, but I don't understand why this would break the search bar entirely, even if my search term was a simple string.
Also I am aware that using two different databases isn't normally something you would do. This application was originally going to be local server based, but the user decided they didn't like the idea after the database was already built...
NOTE I forgot to copy my model:

```
class Tool < ApplicationRecord

    def self.search(search)
        where("prefix ILIKE ? OR basic ILIKE ? OR global ILIKE ? OR suffix ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
        end 
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~ unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873955/actionviewtemplateerror-pgundefinedfunction-error-operator-does-not-exi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an instance variable in the view instead of params:

in your controller:

```
def index
  @search_term = params[:search].to_s
  if params[:search]
    @tools = Tool.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
  else
    @tools = Tool.paginate(params[:page], :per_page => 50)
  end
end
```

In view

```
<%= form_tag(tools_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, @search_term, placeholder: "Search Tools" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This worked thank you, Why does params not work though?

Comment: Probably because `@search_term = params[:search].to_s` insures that the value of passed to your form builder is a string.  It might also work if you did `<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search].to_s, placeholder: "Search Tools" %>`